# Network issues using wsl2 and kali linux

Tags: linux, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux, wsl2

I am running a kali linux terminal using wsl2. I seem to be having some network issus or possebly missing something.

 When I try to ping anything on my local network or outside I get no response at all
I also made a script that should ping every machine connected to the network and I get no response there eiter, here is the code for that :

```
from scapy.all import Ether, ARP, srp
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #If all bits of a MAC address is set to 1 it will broadcast to all devices in a network
    broadcast = "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF"
    #Create a ethernet layer packet
    ether_layer = Ether(dst = broadcast)
    #This represent that we want to scan all devices with IP addresses from 192.168.74.1 up tp 192.168.74.255
    ip_range = "192.168.0.1/24"

arp_layer= ARP(pdst = ip_range)
packet = ether_layer / arp_layer

ans, unans = srp(packet, iface="eth0", timeout=2)

for snd, rcv in ans:
    ip = rcv[ARP].psrc
    mac = rcv[Ether].src
    print("IP = ", ip, " MAC = ", mac)
```

Any tip would be greatly appreciated.[PingTest][1]
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Iqg.png

Comment: Kali is best suited to a real VM (posting from that here) or its own machine (for penetration testing) .

Comment: So I got Kali running on VirtualBox and tried the scrip from there and it worked great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use layer 3 ICMP `ping` to reach other hosts, both on the local network and externally, you appear to be using layer 2 ARP for discovery.

Note that WSL2's layer 2 network is a virtual, internal, Hyper-V network switch.  As such, you aren't going to see hosts on other layer 2 networks using ARP in WSL2.

While WSL2 is great, if you are attempting to learn networking or pen testing with Kali, WSL is likely *not* the right tool for you.  As @John mentioned in the comments, consider a VM or physical machine where you will have more control over the network.